# JavaScript map array based on index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a new array based on the index of the element of the original array. Elements inside the original array are objects, so the goal is to extract the info from two consecutive elements and combine them to the new element: information from no.1 and no.2 form the first element, no.3 and no.4 form the second, etc. The length of the original array is even. How can I do this with `map` function?

A sample: original array:

```
[{name: Name1,age: Age1,year: Year1,desc: Desc1},
 {name: Name2,age: Age2,year: Year2,desc: Desc2},
 {name: Name3,age: Age3,year: Year3,desc: Desc3},
 {name: Name4,age: Age4,year: Year4,desc: Desc4}]
```

And I want to have a new array like this:

```
[{firstName: Name1,
  secondName: Name2,
  firstAge: Age1,
  secondAge: Age2,
  firstYear: Year1,
  seconnTear: Year2,
  firstDesc: Desc1,
  secondDesc: Desc2},

 {firstName: Name3,
  secondName: Name4,
  firstAge: Age3,
  secondAge: Age4,
  firstYear: Year3,
  seconnTear: Year4,
  firstDesc: Desc3,
  secondDesc: Desc4},
  }]
```

Normal looping will of course do it; I just want to know about the use of JavaScript map function.

Comment: Try giving an example of your input and expected output

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, especially since based on your description, `.map()` wouldn't seem to be useful. What's wrong with just writing a simple loop that increments by 2?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't with `map()` The input to `map()` is going to match the output on length.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very typical `Array.prototype.reduce()` work. The following should be able to do what you are after. It will couple the successive two objects in `inArr` first by populating the object with the first data and pushing the it to `reduced` and then populating with the second data at the next round of the reduce operation.

```js
var inArr = [{name: "Name1",age: "Age1",year: "Year1",desc: "Desc1"},
             {name: "Name2",age: "Age2",year: "Year2",desc: "Desc2"},
             {name: "Name3",age: "Age3",year: "Year3",desc: "Desc3"},
             {name: "Name4",age: "Age4",year: "Year4",desc: "Desc4"}],
reduced = inArr.reduce((p,c,i) => { var j = p.length-1;
                                   if (!(i%2)) {
                                     p.push({ firstName: c.name,
                                              secondName: "",
                                                firstAge: c.age,
                                               secondAge: "",
                                               firstYear: c.year,
                                              secondYear: "",
                                               firstDesc: c.desc,
                                              secondDesc: ""});
                                   } else {
                                     p[j].secondName = c.name;
                                     p[j].secondAge  = c.age;
                                     p[j].secondYear = c.year;
                                     p[j].secondDesc = c.desc;
                                   }
                                    return p; }, []);
document.write('<pre> ' + JSON.stringify(reduced, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```